# Merge multiple arrays into one in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do i merge multiple ruby arrays into one. I have tried using the statement below but to no avail

```
@x.concat(@x)
```

This gives me different output

Here is my code in view

```
<% Elements.all.each do |x|  %>
<% @x = Array(x.elements_name) %>
<%= @y = @x.concat(@x) %><br>
<% end %>
```

output

```
["A"]["B"]["C"]
```

What i would like

```
x = ["A","B","C"]
```

How do i do this in ruby?

Comment: `["A"]["B"]["C"]` is not legal ruby syntax

Comment: @Iceman Yeah it is. (It's will raise a NoMethodError because `["A"]["B"]` returns `nil`, but it is syntactically valid.)

Comment: @Jordan Well, that is what I meant, wrong use of words on my behalf :)

Comment: @user2903934 Your question isn't clear. The code you've shown (`x = ["A"]["B"]["C"]`) will produce an error. Please edit your question to include a *working* example of your input.

Comment: Let me rephrase the question to better understand it

Comment: What is the purpose of this code, to output something in the view?

Comment: The purpose is to output results to my jquery script. The script will then populate the elements and auto suggest for the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the elements name you're after with this single line

```
<% x = Elements.all.pluck(:elements_name) %>
```

and then output it or whatever you want to do with it

```
<%= x %>
```

Comment: This is what i was exactly looking for . Thanks Iceman.

Answer (score 0):

You can add arrays to merge them in ruby

```
x = ["A"]+["B"]+["C"]
```